# Looping through NSDictionary and add to NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdictionary

How would I loop through the following `NSDictionary`?

```
2011-10-27 11:40:23.775 Discounts[305:f803] {
    NewDataSet =     {
        Discounts =         (
                        {
                BIN =                 {
                    text = "\n    900020";
                };
                DiscountId =                 {
                    text = "\n  \n    d06dab1b-a2a3-464e-a522-00185fcf5e7c";
                };
                DiscountPrice =                 {
                    text = "\n    75%";
                };
                GRP =                 {
                    text = "\n    8013230";
                };
                PCN =                 {
                    text = "\n    CLAIMNE";
                };
                Title =                 {
                    text = "\n    duralclon";
                };
                UID =                 {
                    text = "\n    100000";
                };
                text = "\n  ";
            },
                        {
                BIN =                 {
                    text = "\n    900020";
                };
                DiscountId =                 {
                    text = "\n  \n    159d9ba9-462c-47a2-a23e-002137c6fd2e";
                };
                DiscountPrice =                 {
                    text = "\n    75%";
                };
                GRP =                 {
                    text = "\n    8013230";
                };
                PCN =                 {
                    text = "\n    CLAIMNE";
                };
                Title =                 {
                    text = "\n    allermax";
                };
                UID =                 {
                    text = "\n    100001";
                };
                text = "\n  ";
            },
...
```

I've tried:

```
for (id key in discountsDict) {
  MyObject *obj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
  obj.Title = (NSString *)[key objectForKey:@"Title"]; // *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x6ca2eb0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Title.'
  [self.discounts addObject:obj];
  [obj release];
}
```

Not quite sure whether I'm meant to be creating an `NSArray` with the contents and then loop through that in order to add `MyObject` to my `NSMutableArray` of `self.discounts`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Danie: Added the error as a comment next to the line that throws the error.

Comment: Can you dump the dictionary in objective c style, `NSLog(@"%@", discountsDict)` and post it?

Comment: @Dani: Dumped in objective-c style.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You're asking `key` for `objectForKey:@"Title"`, but `key` is just an `NSString*`. What you really mean is `[[discountsDict objectForKey:key] objectForKey:@"Title"]`. Or, if you're supporting 4.0 and higher, you can use

```
[discountsDict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id val, BOOL *stop){
    MyObject *obj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
    obj.Title = [val objectForKey:@"Title"];
    [self.discounts addObject:obj];
    [obj release];
}];
```

Comment: My target framework is 4.0 and I'm on Xcode 4.2 and I get the following warning: `// Instance method enumerateObjectsAndKeysUsingBlock not found`

Comment: Also: `NSString *title = (NSString *)[[discountsDict objectForKey:key] objectForKey:@"Title"];` didn't work either. It's returning `nil` for `Title`.

Comment: Fixed, it's actually: `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock` not `enumerateObjectsAndKeysUsingBlock`. Warning stops but still having `Title` returning `null`.

Comment: Could it be because it's actually: `Title =                 {
                    text = "\n    duralclon";
                };` it's the 'text' object that holds the value?

Answer (score -1):

You do realize that there is only one element ("NewDataSet") in that dictionary, right?

Comment: Yes, and you do realise you've added this as an answer instead of a comment, right?